# Sudo dd is a directory

Tags: sudo, mbr

I am trying to backup the MBR to a folder called **MBRbackup** under /etc directory. When I run the command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda  of=/etc/MBRbackup bs=512 count=1
```

I get the the message:

```
dd: failed to open '/etc/MBRbackup': Is a directory
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong to figure a way to back it up to **MBRbackup** folder

Comment: you have to back up to a file

Comment: @ravery after creating the MBRback under /etc am not able to find when I run the command ls -a. Also I created MBRbackup under MBRback directory and the same thing I can not find them when I run ls -a

Comment: did you use `sudo`? /etc is owned by root

Comment: @ravery Yes I did

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/etc/MBRbackup/sdambr.bak`

Comment: @ravery copied but still can not see the MBRbackup folder when I run ls under /etc

Comment: did you make the folder? again this requires sudo

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by creating a file inside my `/etc/MBRbackup` directory

```
dd if=/dev/sda  of=/etc/MBRbacku/MBR bs=512 count=1
```